# Why Java does not see a native library on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have a problem including a native library to my Java project on Linux Ubuntu.

A directory `/mnt` contains files `treedb.jar` and `jkyotocabinet.so` which are needed for launching:

```
root@vtt9:/mnt# ls -l

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1948919 Mar 11  2014 jkyotocabinet.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1404322 Nov 18 16:11 treedb.jar
```

I start the program with param `-Djava.library.path=.`:

```
root@vtt9:/mnt# sudo java -Xms5000m -Xmx51000m -d64 -jar
-Djava.library.path=. treedb.jar
```

The program prints strings to the console:

```
current dir = /mnt/.
java library path = .
```

Then I have an exception on `System.loadLibrary("jkyotocabinet");`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jkyotocabinet in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at treedb.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Also I looked in `java -XshowSettings:properties`, put `jkyotocabinet.so` to another directories in `java.library.path`, set programmatically `System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "." );`

I don't understand what is wrong with it? On Windows it works great. I need only replace `.so` to `.dll`.

Comment: What happens when you set `-Djava.library.path=/mnt`?

Comment: @TMN , thanks! I found my mistake! It was problem with kyotocabinet ( i just rename jkyotocabinet.so to libjkyotokabinet.so and it works fine )